# How to select particular rows partially?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table contains 100 rows. I want to display first 10 rows in one page and next 10 rows in another page and so on. Would you please help me how to do it?

Comment: I used If conditions but it doesn't work.

Comment: You can do this with pagination by using parameters like PageNo, RowsToDisplay in stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks but how to do it. I need example

Comment: "I used If conditions" - would you be so kind as to edit your attempt into the question?

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        Id,
        column1,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) AS RowNum
    FROM
        yourtable
)
SELECT
    Id,
    column1
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN @Start AND @End
```